# How can I add Interface of dervived types to a dictionary of interfaces of base type

Tags: c#

I am trying to create a class where I can register a bunch of different handlers for requests that the application must service. The request produces a response that will be sent back to the remote. I have an interface for anything that can handle the request. All requests and responses inherit from ProtoBase. (The protobase class handles the serialization of its state into a byte array). The interface is below.

```
public interface IHandler<TReq, TResp> 
    where TReq: ProtoBase
    where TResp: ProtoBase
{
    TResp Handle(TReq, object origin);
}
```

```
public class Foo
{
    private Dictionary<ReqType, IHandler<ProtoBase, ProtoBase>> handlers;

    public Foo()
    {
        handlers = new Dictionary<ReqType, IHandler<ProtoBase, ProtoBase>>();
    }

    public void RegisterHandler(IHandler<BarRequest, BarResp> fooBarHandler)
    {
        handlers[ReqType.FooBar] = fooBarHandler;
    }
    
    public void Run()
    {
        while(true)
        {
            var req = GetRequest();
            var handler = handlers[req.ReqType];
            var resp = handler.Handle(req);
            Send(resp);
        }
    }

}
```

The code above produces a compiler error

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'IHandler<BarRequest, BarResp>' to 'IHandler<ProtoBase, ProtoBase>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

I tried playing with contravariance and covariance on the interface but it made no difference.

Comment: It would be easier if you extended your sample so it actually compiles (save for the one error you're trying to solve). Providing the context manually is certainly possible, but tedious.

Comment: What are BarRequest and BarResponse? can we see their class definitions. I assume they inherit from Protobase, but would be good to confirm

Comment: i dont know much about inheritance laws but wouldn't there be a cast required when passing in something to the RegisterHandler function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot make `IHandler<ProtoBase, ProtoBase>` a superclass for your specific handlers, no matter how much you play around with co- and contravariance.

Why? Let's assume this were possible, then we could have the following code:

```
IHandler<SomeRequest, SomeResponse> specificHandler = ...;
IHandler<ProtoBase, ProtoBase> handler = specificHandler; // won't work, but let's assume it does

// Should work from a type system POV, since SomeOtherRequest also inherits from ProtoBase,
// but can't work from a logic POV, since your handler can only handle SomeRequest.
handler.Handle(new SomeOtherRequest());
```

Answer (score 3):

For that cast to work, it would need to be `IHandler<out TReq, out TResp>`, but in terms of variance, your `Handle` method is only compatible with `IHandler<in TReq, out TResp>`.

So: you can't. You might need to make the type actually implement `IHandler<ProtoBase, ProtoBase>`.